# What information is missing from the SO community dump?

Tags: discussion, community-data

What information do you think is missing from the community data dump?

As it stands I think the current data dump contains most of the information we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full revision history, including when & who voted to open, close, delete, undelete, etc

Answer (score 1):

Deleted posts

I can understand why this wasn't included (offensive, potentially illegal posts have been deleted), but it's frustrating to have the ability to see deleted posts in the system but not have a good way to search them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still very interested in vote times.