# Rep analysis using the community dump, missing information

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-dump

The current Community-Dump is missing a the date field that shows when a question or answer was flipped to community wiki.

Assuming this date field is added, it will not be enough to simulate a rep recalc, and determine how much rep each person got from each question.

The Votes are scrubbed and have a 24 hour fidelity, meaning that the community wiki date + the votes table would not be enough to determine rep-per-question or answer.

Would it be possible to add total non-community-wiki votes to posts, in the next dump?

Related: [What information is missing from the SO community dump?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/what-information-is-missing-from-the-so-community-dump)

Comment: There's a lot of little things that will make calculating rep from the dump impossible. If x isn't the limiting factor it will be y. :(

Comment: This will be available in the next export